# iOS and Xcode : folder reference doesn't override an older folder reference

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

- I have an iOS Xcode project that contain a folder reference , lets name it "F".
- When building the project the "F" folder is copied as is into the iOS application package.
- When deploying the app on the device , the "F" folder is copied as is to the application folder in the device.
- "F" is a folder that contain a big hierarchy of sub-folders with many files in it.
- As a side note , not really related to the problem but might worth a mention : "F" is basically a web app that contains css,html , JS and images that is loaded into a WebView.

My problem is in the following scenario (using an iOS simulator):

1. I build the project
2. I run the app from Xcode (which means that the app is deployed on the device emulator)
3. Everything is fine
4. I close the app
5. I change some file in "F" (assume I changed something in a css style of some page)
6. I build the project again
7. I run the app (which means that the app is deployed on the device emulator on top of the app that was deployed on step 2)

desired result : The change I done at step 5 is there

actual result : The change I done in step 5 is not there

After some investigation (Using web inspectors and looking on the package content as well as on the application folder) , I have found out that the changed file doesn't override the older file.

A workaround is doing the following steps between 5 and 6 (Both steps are required):

5.1 delete the app from the simulator
5.2 clean the Xcode project

Only then the changed file will exist on the device.

You may ask what's the problem If I have that work around. Well, while cleaning a project (5.2) is always a good thing to do, I am more worried about 5.1. I am worried about updates , in update the old application is not deleted but rather the new version is installed on top of the old which is kind of more or less happening in scenario that is described above.

In an update, the changed files won't override the older files.

Anyone know how can I force the folder reference contents to completely override an older folder reference when deploying a new package on top of an older package (or in other words , when doing an update) ?

P.S. : The described issue happens only when using folder reference.

Comment: Not sure why you're using the objective c tag when your main problems seem to be including CSS/JS stuff loaded into a web view.  What you want is a custom build script for your build phase, and so Xcode would be the only good tag. Though I've needed that in the past I can't help you there.